# ¿Cómo deshabilitar input text en formulario?

Tags: javascript, html

La cuestión es la siguiente tengo un simple formulario de ordenes de trabajo, en **este caso a modo de prueba estoy creando una nueva orden**, como tengo un solo archivo blade para la creación y edición de las ordenes de trabajo lo que quiero lograr es **habilitar input text MOTIVO solo si se selecciona la opcion NO TERMINADO  de mi select** ,este campo status tiene 3 opciones: "en proceso", "terminado" y "no terminado".**

Esta es una imagen de mi formulario actualmente:

[image: Orden]

como se puede observar en la imagen **quiero habilitar el input motivo solo si selecciona la opcion NO TERMINADO**

Este es mi modelo:

```
class Order extends Model implements Auditable
{

    protected $fillable = ['client_id', 'user_id', 'num', 'name_product', 'status', 'date'];

    public $timestamps = true;  

    protected $dates = ['date'];

    protected $status = [
        'EN PROCESO'    => 'En proceso',
        'TERMINADO'     => 'Terminado',
        'NO TERMINADO'  => 'No terminado'
    ];    

    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }
```

Este es mi OrderController:

```
  public function create()
    { 
        $order = new Order();      

        $this->authorize('create', $order);


        return view('admin.orders.partials.form', [
            'clients'   => Client::all(),
            'users'     => User::NotRole(['Admin', 'Supervisor'])->get(),
            'products'  => Order::pluck('name_product', 'name_product'),
            'order'     => $order
        ]);  

    }

public function edit($id)
    {   
        $order = Order::findOrFail($id);

        $this->authorize('update', $order);            

        return view('admin.orders.partials.form', [
            'clients'   => Client::all(),
            'users'     => User::NotRole(['Admin', 'Supervisor'])->get(),
            'products'  => Order::pluck('name_product', 'name_product'),
            'order'     => $order
        ]);        

    }
```

archivo blade:

Bueno en esta parte quiero aplicar la lógica si el usuario selecciona la opcion NO TERMINADO se deberia habilitar el input text Motivo
Asi es como lo estoy intentando pero no me funciona 
Como obtengo la opcion seleccionada de mi select para asi poder realizar la verificacion?

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Detalle de la orden</h3>                
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">

                <div class="form-group">              
                    {!! Form::label('status', 'Estado') !!}                         
                    {!! Form::select('status', $order->getStatus(), '[0]', ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'status']) !!}                                                 
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('reason', 'Motivo') !!}
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        </div>      
                        @if ( $order->getStatus('[2]') === 'NO TERMINADO')              
                        {!! Form::text('reason', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'reason', 'placeholder' => 'Motivo']) !!}
                        @else
                        {!! Form::text('reason', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'reason', 'disabled' => 'disabled', 'placeholder' => 'Motivo']) !!}
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Bueno espero que me puedan ayudar con este cambio que le quiero realizar a mi formulario.
Gracias por su tiempo voy a estar atento a sus comentarios!
Saludos!!

Comment: Existe alguna manera de realizar esa comprobación en mi vista balde ?  O como realizarlo en el controlador ?

Comment: Con el atributo `disabled` deshabilitas un input, condiciónalo desde tu script

Comment: me parece demasiado *rebuscada* la forma en que lo haces, cuando con JS sería mas simple

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creo que la opción mas natural y funcional en este caso **es manejarlo a través de JS**, del modo siguiente:

- Desde el HTML agrégale a tu etiqueta `input` el atributo `disabled` para que por default este deshabilitada y solo se vuelva a habilitar mediante la lógica que se escriba en JS
- Cada elemento involucrado agrégale un `id` tanto para el `input` como para la etiqueta `select`
- Obtén por medio de su `id` y asignalo a una variable al `select` para que después por medio de su evento `change` verifiquemos el valor que el usuario elige de la lista desplegable
- Por medio de un condicional simple `if else` verificamos si la propiedad `value` es igual a `2` por ejemplo y con base en eso....
- Si el valor elegido es 2 entonces la propiedad `disabled` la pasamos a `false`
- En caso contrario a la condición anterior mantenemos la propiedad `disabled` en `true`

**Ejemplo**

El siguiente ejemplo es fácil de adaptar tan solo ten en cuenta:

- Los nombres de los id
- El código JS que recupera en las variables los valores de los nodos HTML

Código

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="#">
      Valor 1 <input id="deshabilitado" disabled type="text" />
      <p>Selecciona la opción 2 para habilitar</p>
      <select name="" id="opciones">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    <script>
        let opcion = document.getElementById("opciones")
        let caja   = document.getElementById("deshabilitado")
        
        opcion.addEventListener("change", () => {
          let elementoElegido = opcion.options[opcion.selectedIndex].value
          if (elementoElegido === "2") {
            caja.disabled = false
          } else {
            caja.disabled = true
          } 
        })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

*Nota importante*

Si la comprobación la quieres realizar a nivel del texto que esta entre las etiquetas de apertura y cierre `option`, entonces sustituye el uso de `.value` por `.text`

**Referencias**

- [**`selectedIndex`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex)
- [**`select value`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement)

Comment: si realmente es rebuscado pero no se me ocurría otra manera . Gracias por responder luego pruebo y comento

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió de mucho tu ejemplo